# HTML5 FileReader - upload a CSV file and display its content as raw binary (strings of 0s and 1s)

Tags: javascript, html

I need to upload a CSV file and push its content as a series of 0s and 1s to an end point.

Example: abc.csv ===> "01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111...."

When I am trying with the existing FileReader.readAsBinaryString(), the console.log is displaying the text of the csv file.

Eg.

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = evt => {
    result = evt.target.result;
    console.log(result);
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

Output: coming as raw text of the uploaded csv file.

Appreciate any help here.

Thanks.

Comment: So, what's the problem? You're successfully reading a file's contents, from the looks of it.

Comment: That's right. However, am not sure how to display the content as a string of zeroes and ones.

Comment: Display where? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hey Cerbrus, here is the thing. There is another API end-point that accepts the upload file as a stream of binary strings. I'm trying to push the content of the uploaded file as a part of POST payload. POST payload structure(content-type: application/json") is something like - {"name": "abc.csv", "content":"0100010001......"}. Hope this clarifies you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) to convert a byte into bits. Using the AND operator (a single '&'), you can check whether a bit is set or not. The following code is an example:

```
var bits = [
    0x80, // 10000000
    0x40, // 01000000
    0x20, // 00100000
    0x10, // 00010000
    0x08, // 00001000
    0x04, // 00000100
    0x02, // 00000010
    0x01  // 00000001
];

// convert 'true' or 'false' to '1' or '0'
function boolToBinary(b){
    return (b) ? '1' : '0';
}

// convert a byte to a binary string
function byteToBinary(b){
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        // check if bit 'i' is set
        output += boolToBinary(b & bits[i]);

    return output;
}

// convert a string to a binary string
function strToBinary(s){
    if (!s) return '';

    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        // use charCodeAt to convert a char to a byte: ('A' => 65)
        output += byteToBinary(s.charCodeAt(i)) + ' ';

    return output.slice(0, -1);
}

console.log(strToBinary('HALLO'));

for (var i = 1; i < 256; i*=2)
    console.log(byteToBinary(i) + ' == ' + i);
```

The console output would be:

```
01001000 01000001 01001100 01001100 01001111
00000001 == 1
00000010 == 2
00000100 == 4
00001000 == 8
00010000 == 16
00100000 == 32
01000000 == 64
10000000 == 128
```

Which seems to be your expected output as well.

However, please do note that there are is some variation possible. The code above uses Little Endian, meaning that the byte is right-to-left (used in Windows for example). You could also use Big Endian. You should match your API. To convert the code above to Big Endian, simply reverse the bits array (starting low, ending high).
Also, I wrote the code for ASCII characters, with one byte per character. Unicode uses two bytes per character. For Unicode; first split the charcode in two bytes, like so:

```
function strToBinary(s){
    if (!s) return '';

    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        var charCode = s.charCodeAt(i);
        var charCode_lo = charCode & 0x00FF;
        var charCode_hi = (charCode & 0xFF00) >> 8;

        output += byteToBinary(charCode_hi) + ' ';
        output += byteToBinary(charCode_lo) + ' ';
    }

    return output.slice(0, -1);
}
```

And again, for Big Endian, switch the output order.